# Not able to get the correct size of the screen in android 2.3?

Tags: android, screen-size

I am trying to get the size of the screen. The size I have set for emulator is 540 x 960 but what I am getting is 320 x 480. Any suggestions on it to get the right size. Here is the code;

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
width = dm.widthPixels;
height = dm.heightPixels;
```

Comment: I guess you are targeting Android 1.5. (API level 3)? This version only supported this basic resolution, support for multiple displays came mostly with 1.6. If this is the case, the display manager only reports this resolution. Have a look at [Strategies for 1.5.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-support-1.5.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I have set my API Level at 10 only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
int height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
int width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
```

Comment: I guess you are using emulator running android 1.5-2.0.
goto manifest.xml and add the following code.

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>